# I am trying to find a story where a children's nursery turns into a jungle

Tags: story-identification

I read this short story(I believe it was under novella length, but I could be mistaken) a while back, and I am trying to identify the title for a friend.

Plot:

> Parents(male and female) get a computer aided/holographic nursery for their children. The mother becomes increasingly agitated as the children withdraw more. The children are barely even featured in the story, and the ending concludes with lions possibly eating the parents.

Publishing date: Years ago.

Tech level: Seemingly functional AI, not much more.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The story is [*The Veldt*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt) by Ray Bradbury.

It's pretty close to what you describe.  The kids spend more and more time in the nursery, in the artificial environment it provides and grow to prefer it over their own home life with their parents.

Then:

> The parents find the veldt environment that the nursery replicates and that the kids love is not entirely artificial.  In the end, you're right, the parents get trapped in the artificial (now real) veldt environment and are killed by lions.

Comment: I remember reading this in *The Illustrated Man* as a kid.

Comment: I remember reading this as part of "The Ray Bradbury Chronicles".

Comment: Just saw a reference in Masters of Doom and remembered this, figured I'd check to see if it had been answered.

Comment: The story was also adapted for Bradbury's "Ray Bradbury Theatre" tv series back in the 1980s..  The episode can be found on youtube, if anyone is interested.