# short story with kids who are so spoiled the set lions on their parents when told "no"?

Tags: story-identification

I read this story ten years ago, and can't find it or remember it's name. It's about two kids who live in a house that spoils them.They have a holo room that turns into Africa when they play in it. I think their parents tell them to stop doing something with the room, so they set lions on their parents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ["The Veldt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_%28short_story%29) by Ray Bradbury.

A similar question [has been answered before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9005/19561) with more details.

Comment: AAAHHHH! thanks. been meaning to show that to some friends, but couldnt remember what it was.

Comment: oh. i looked, but couldn't find it. my mistake.