# Story about a really advanced room (called a "Nursery"), that makes realistic images, and ends in the main character's death

Tags: story-identification

No idea when this was made, but the room (and the house) are all electronic. The "Nursery" is primarily Africa. The parents (main characters), try to change it from Africa. The parents also hear screaming in the night. The children, Wendy and Peter, keep it set to Africa, but quickly change it. Soon the parents call a psychiatrist, and after a little bit of stuff I can't remember, the parents attempt to shut it off. The children say they wish they were dead. Then the parents let it on for 1 more night, but then they enter in the middle of the night to turn it off (more screaming), the door locks and the parents "realize why the screaming sounded so familiar" as lions cornered them. The psychiatrist then comes in the next day, asking the children where their parents were, and they say they will be there soon.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/i-am-trying-to-find-a-story-where-a-childrens-nursery-turns-into-a-jungle (which is already a hub for other duplicates)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[The Veldt by Ray Bradbury.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_(short_story))

> The Hadley family lives in an automated house called "the Happylife Home,” filled with machines that aid them in completing everyday tasks, such as tying their shoes, bathing them, or cooking their food. The two children, Peter and Wendy,[a] enjoy time in the "nursery", a virtual reality room able to realistically reproduce any place they imagine, and grow increasingly attached to it.
>
> The parents, George and Lydia, begin to wonder if there is something wrong with their way of life. Lydia tells George, "That's just it. I feel like I don't belong here. The house is wife and mother now, and nursemaid. Can I compete with an African veldt? Can I give a bath and scrub the children as efficiently or quickly as the automatic scrub bath can? I cannot."[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_(short_story)#Adaptations) They are perplexed that the nursery is stuck on an African landscape setting, with lions in the distance, eating an unidentifiable animal carcass. There they also find recreations of their personal belongings and hear strangely familiar screams. Wondering why their children are so concerned with this scene of death, they decide to call a psychologist.
>
> The psychologist, David McClean, suggests they turn off the house, move to the country, and learn to be more self-sufficient. Peter and Wendy strongly resist and beg their parents to let them have one last visit to the nursery. They give in and allow the children more time in the nursery. When George and Lydia come to fetch them, the children lock their parents into the nursery with the pride of lions, the two realizes that the screams belonged to simulated versions of themselves. Shortly after, David comes by to look for George and Lydia. He finds the children enjoying lunch in the nursery and sees the lions and vultures eating carcasses in the distance, which are implied to be the parents.

When you say "when it was made"  are you talking about a film/TV show?
The story has been [adapted several times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_(short_story)#Adaptations), but most likely you saw an episode of *The Ray Bradbury Theatre*. Or it might have been one of the segments in [The Illustrated Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illustrated_Man_(film)).